# How to run the bin file on m2 mac

Tags: macos, binary, arm

I run the command "cp /bin/cat test" on the mac terminal, and then execute "./test", the process will be killed and exit directly. The mac is a 2023 m2 chip. I don’t have this problem on my old mac. In other non-m2 It can also run normally on the mac. I suspect that it is the problem of the m2 chip, but I don't know how to solve it.I really need some help!

It works fine on other non-m2 macs, but not on my latest m2

Comment: Try running `file test` to see what kind of file it is.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a hardware issue, and I was able to reproduce this on an M1 Mac as well, and with other executables in /bin/.

This *feels* like a security feature to prevent system binaries from being executed outside of /bin/, but I can't find any documentation about such a feature, and I couldn't reproduce it on my x86_64 Mac

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing this I checked the crash reports in Console.app and found this:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL (Code Signature Invalid))
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Termination Reason: CODESIGNING 4 Launch Constraint Violation
```

So it's not the CPU causing this, it's the operating system.